# How to identify name, UUID, RSSI and approximate distance of BTLE devices using iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-bluetooth

I want to write an iOS app that list down all the nearby bluetooth devices along with their name, UUID, RSSI and approximate distance from my current location. I explored CoreBlueTooth API and created a central manager but that does not help. Below is what I have done so far. After 30 seconds of scanning I do not find any device near me but when I go to device settings and bluetooth section, it shows a list of devices. Any idea what could be wrong here?

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
}

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central {
    if (central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn) {
        return;
    }

    [self scan];
}


- (void)scan
{
    self.anAcivityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    self.anAcivityIndicator.center = self.view.center;
    [self.anAcivityIndicator startAnimating];
    [self.view addSubview:self.anAcivityIndicator];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 target:self selector:@selector(stopScanning) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];
    NSLog(@"Scanning started");
}


- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSString *aBeaconName = peripheral.name;
    NSUUID *anIdentifier = peripheral.identifier;
    if (aBeaconName && anIdentifier) {
        [self.beaconUUID setObject:anIdentifier forKey:aBeaconName];
    }

}

- (void)stopScanning {
    [self.centralManager stopScan];

    if ([self.beaconUUID count] > 0) {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *anAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Data" message:@"No beacon found!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [anAlertView show];
    }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)iAlertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)iButtonIndex {
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: The device you're seing in the Settings.apps are BLE or classical bluetooth?

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the enhancements to [CoreLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CoreLocation_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007123) framework for iOS 7. I can't say much more than that without breaking NDA, but I think you might find some helpful beacons to guide your way. :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all in the iOS settings show all Bluetooth devices (BLE and not BLE). According to your code it can detect only Bluetooth Low Energy devices working in peripheral mode. Please be sure that u have at list one BLE devices working in peripheral mode (for instance iBeacon). Usually for the detecting BLE devices in Central or Peripheral mode use to classical BT framework. For the iBeacon devices better to apply CoreLocation framework.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Right. Corrected  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

BLE return a signal strength parameter that can be use to find device proximity . if you can get it from  core Bluetooth  you ll able to use in the path loss equation and find device closest to you